Generating season matches with Laravel?
I've wrote a command to generate a season record along with matches between teams.
It works great, but it doesn't seem to take into account if a team already has a match.
This means, team 1 could play team 3, but team 4 could also play team 1, meaning team 1 has two matches on day one?
How can I fix this and avoid matches overlapping?
class GenerateSeasonCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'generate:season';
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    public function handle(): void
    {
        $season = Season::query()->create([
            'name' => $this->ask('What is the name of the season?'),
        ]);

        $seasonGameData = [];
        $teams = Team::all();

        foreach ($teams as $team) {
            $matchDay = 0;
            foreach (Team::query()->whereNot('id', $team->id)->get() as $otherTeam) {
                $matchDay++;
                $seasonGameData[] = [
                    'season_id' => $season->id,
                    'home_team_id' => $team->id,
                    'away_team_id' => $otherTeam->id,
                    'game_mode_id' => $this->getRandomGameModeId(),
                    'map_id' => Map::query()->orderByRaw('RAND()')->first()->id,
                    'match_day' => $matchDay,
                    'created_at' => now()
                ];
            }
        }

        SeasonGame::query()->insert($seasonGameData);
    }

    private function getRandomGameModeId() : int
    {
        return mt_rand(1, 4) >= 4 ?
            mt_rand(1, 4) :
            mt_rand(1, 3);
    }
}


If you want only one match in a day you can move $matchDay outside the for loop

Welcome @ash. If there were four teams, do you only want for example matches between 1-3 and 2-4 in one day?

This question is similar to: Algorithm: Selecting pairs of teams from a set of games. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
